# I'm trying to get the localStorage but encountering an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I'm using redux/toolkit, when I logged in to my user, I get all the information and store the value in the localStorage.

What I'm trying to do is the authentication, after the user login, it will store its information to the localStorage,then make the navbar dynamic, but before I even execute that, I'm already having a problem here

[image: localStorage]

but after refreshing the page, or redirecting it to another URL, I get this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'e', "eyJhbGciOi"... is not valid JSON
```

It says it has an error at UserSlice.js

and this is my dispatch action/api calls

```
export const loginUser = async (userData, dispatch) =>{
    dispatch(loginStart())
    try {
        const res = await publicRequest.post('/auth/login', userData)
        const item = res.data?.accessToken
        localStorage.setItem('user', item)
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data))
    } catch (error) {
        const message =
        "Wrong Username or Email "
        dispatch(loginFailure(message))
    }
}
```

UserSlice.js

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState : {
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: ''
  },
  reducers: {
    resetStates: (state) =>{
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.message = ""
    },
    loginStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
    },
    loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.isSuccess = true;
      state.user = action.payload
    },
    loginFailure: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isError = true;
      state.message = action.payload
      state.user = null
    },
    logoutUser: (state) =>{
      state.user = null
    }
  }

})

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure, resetStates, logoutUser} = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer
```

Am I doing it correctly or am I approaching it bad?

Comment: If you use JSON parse you need to use JSON.stringify. Just remove the JSON.parse since it is just a string: `user: localStorage.getItem("user") || null,`

Comment: Local storage bad. Insecure. JWT bad. Also insecure.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you did, you have set the LocalStorage Item as a "string".

You cant Parse a String with JSON.parse.

You have to use JSON.stringify() since this method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string.

Here is the Link for JSON.stringify() : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

According to **@mplungjan**'s comment, with `JSON.parse()` you can parse only JSON (the string that can be parsed as a JSON). But the value `localStorage.getItem("user")` isn't JSON.

Just use `localStorage.getItem("user") || null`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do if you don't want to change your data storing type in `localStorage`

```js
..
 initialState : {
    user: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("user"))) || null,
    // or user: localStorage.getItem('user') || null,
    // both of them correct
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: ''
  },
..
```

**I recommend to you to use
`user: localStorage.getItem('user') || null`**

---

***Optional***

*But I can suggest you for naming and modelling data that will be stored in `localStorage`. The value that storing in localStorage is access token of user. It is not user. So you can set the item like this*:

```js
// storing in obj.
const user = { token: <access_token> };
..
// stringifying for storage
localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
..
// parsing for access
user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
```